# Sudden change in latency in Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I run an app on AWS elastic beanstalk with php, EC2, and mysql 5.6 (RDS). There are currently about 5k hits/min each resulting in multiple db operations per hit. I have noticed that when ever I make a change in code or db and resume the service, the average latency starts very low (10ms range), but after few hours, i see a sudden jump to ~200mS. I am attaching some screen shots of the latency graph.

Given the codebase is running for hours with 10mS latency, I am confused as to whether it is the code itself causing this issue as it seems fine when starting off. I have been optimizing my code over time to fine tune resource usage, db calls, etc and it definitely has helped but I cannot figure out why this sharp jump in latency which occurs in few hours.

Even when latency goes up, the connections or cpu usage does not really move much.

Where can I start/ How can I go about troubleshooting this?

[image: Average Latency]
[image: Minumum Latency]
[image: Maximum Latency]
[image: dB Dashboard stats]

**Update:**

```
Variable_name                         Value
innodb_stats_auto_recalc              ON
innodb_stats_include_delete_marked    OFF
innodb_stats_method                   nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata              OFF
innodb_stats_persistent               ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages  20
innodb_stats_sample_pages             8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages   8
```

Comment: Please post results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_stats%' for analysis.

Comment: Do you have any update on this? Need more info to help out. Can you plot your innodb utilization and network utilization against time as well?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have posted an update with results of your query. But this is recent and not when the actual event happened. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: @KarthikRajan Is that something I can do on my phpmyAdmin interface? or on AWS RDS?

Comment: Innodb utilization -> That is not part of AWS RDS. You'd need to plot it manually (by querying the status variables of mysql) or use some standard db monitoring tool (like percona or sorts). Network utilization is part of the AWS RDS if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @aVC  Reviewing the graphs from 11/8 and 11/9/2018 it appears that ~ 15 mins into each hour a function is triggered that drives the latency up for a period of time.  Possibly the php garbage collection that is on an hourly cycle - 3600 seconds.  Of the three graphs, not quite sure why one of the graphs indicates 60 SECONDS of latency and the other two are not as severe.   Not really sure if the graphs are from php, ec2 or MySQL but they are from same appx hours of the day.  For further assistance view my profile, Network profile for contact information and get in touch, please.